# Sorting and making rows have the same index pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames i wonder if there is a way to sort the second data frame based on the id column in the first one and then make the duplicates have the same index (rows with the same value in the id column in the second data frame)

df1

```
index        id        name
0            24       'Samy'
1            53        'Sara'
```

df2

```
index        id        hobby
0            53        'reading'
1            53        'swimming'
2            24        'running'
```

Expected output:

```
index        id        hobby
0            24        'running'
1            53        'reading'
1            53        'swimming'
```

Comment: Any reason to not just use ID as the index?

Comment: No.. using ID as the index is also accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df2.index=df2.id.map(dict(zip(df1.id,df1.index)))
df2=df2.sort_index()
df2
    id       hobby
id                
0   24   'running'
1   53   'reading'
1   53  'swimming'
```